# IIS crashes (browser returns breakpoint error) when datatable is being filled with large number of elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC asp.net application that takes in a .txt file and returns the number of occurrences of each word. And it all works fine until i use bigger files(it breaks with,4-5 mb). I have done all the necessary settings in web.config.

I can see that on the browser it the datatable is being filled, but at one point it just returns the error.
I am sending the data from controller to view in IEnumerable form, its practically a list of objects(word,wordCount). Can somebody explain how i can fix it?

Controller method that accepts the txt file, and returns the view with the model inside:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Calculate(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
       

        bool result = false;
        StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength == 0)
                throw new Exception("Zero length file!");
            else
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Document"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
                {
                    result = true;
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Document"), fileName)))
                    {
                        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                        {
                            strbuild.AppendFormat(sr.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }

        String s1 = strbuild.ToString();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(s1.Split(' ', ',', ':', ';', '!', '?', '.', '"', '(', ')', ']', '[', '}', '{', '\''));
        IDictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        
       foreach(String l in list)
        {
            if (l.Length > 1)
            {

                if (dict.ContainsKey(l.ToLower()))
                {
                    dict[l.ToLower()] = dict[l.ToLower()] + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(l.ToLower(), 1);
                }
            }
        }
        if (dict.ContainsKey("")) dict.Remove("");

        dict=dict.OrderBy(key => key.Value).ToDictionary(key=>key.Key, key=>key.Value);

        List<WordModel> words = new List<WordModel>();
        
        

        for (int i=0; i<dict.Count(); i++)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rec: {0}, Broj Ponavljanja: {1}", dict.ElementAt(i).Key, dict.ElementAt(i).Value);
            WordModel word = new WordModel(dict.ElementAt(i).Key,dict.ElementAt(i).Value);
            words.Add(word);
            
          

        }
        words.Sort();
        words.Reverse();
        
        

        
        
        //ViewData["dict"] = wordsArray;
        return View(words.AsEnumerable());
    }
```

View that crashes (returns the status_beakpoint error ):

```
     @using WordCounter.Models;



    @model IEnumerable<WordCounter.Models.WordModel>
 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Word Frequency Calculator";

  //Layout = null;
  //var dict = (IDictionary<string, int>)ViewData["dict"];
  // dict = dict.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).ToDictionary(key => 
 key.Key, key => key.Value);
  }





      <h2>Calculate</h2>








         @using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate",
                    "Home",
                    FormMethod.Post,
                    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
      {
     <label for="file">Upload file:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
       <br>
       <br>

       <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />

        <br>
     <br>

     @ViewBag.Message
}



    <table class="table" style="table-layout:fixed"id="datatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Word
        </th>
        <th>
            Word Count
        </th>

       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.word)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.wordCount)
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
  </tbody>

</table>

   @section scripts{
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/af- 
 2.3.5/datatables.min.css" />

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt- 
 1.10.22/af-2.3.5/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datatable").DataTable({
             " processing": true,
             " serverSide": true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "AutoWidth": false,
            "LengthChange": false,
            //pokusaj popravke problema sa velikim podacima...
        }  );
    })
 </script>


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of IIS are you running? Default max request size in IIS 6 is 4 MB.

When you say it breaks, what exactly does the error say?

If you're using IIS 6, open IIS Manager, navigate to your site, and open Request Filtering. On the right, hit Edit Feature Settings. In the Request Limits area of the Settings window, up your Max allowed content length to what you need.

Trivially but worth mentioning, you can add an attribute to your MVC action to up the size limit just for that type of request, ie

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
public IActionResult Foo...
```

Comment: Im running IIS Express 10. So the thing is it breaks when i send the view that contains the large data-set to client. It starts loading up the page, even fills up the table but then it breaks and the browser returns status_breakpoint? I will edit my post now so you can see the code of the method that accepts the txt file, parses it and then returns the view with the model(that is a large list of objects). The backend i think does its part, i would say the problem is at the browser.